# Absolute vaule of an input of a list of integers using map() function

Tags: python, list, integer

Usually, when I have to input a *list* of space-separated integers in this fashion:

```
12 15 31 -12
```

I use this function:

```py
list(map(int, input().split()))
```

So that it returns `[12, 15, 31, -12]`.

But, now, if for some reason I have to input the numbers as positive integers only (ie. their absoulte value), how should I go with it the easiest way?
I could very well input all the numbers in the list and then one by one, convert them to their absolute value, but is their a better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial once you understand what the `map(func, iterable)` function does: it calls the function `func` on *each element* of the given `iterable`, and returns an iterator containing the results. It's equivalent to doing this:

```
def my_map(func, iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield func(item)
```

So how do you get the absolute integer value? Change what `func` does!

1. Define a function and `map` to that:

```
def absint(x):
    return abs(int(x))

list(map(absint, input().split()))
```

2. Define a lambda function that calls `abs` and `int`:

```
list(map(lambda x: abs(int(x)), input().split()))
```

1 and 2 are essentially the same, I don't expect there to be any difference in performance between the two.

Answer (score 3):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[abs(int(x)) for x in input().split()]
```